# Mapbox auto fill complete address

Tags: mapbox, autofill

I use mapbox tools for my autofill place address autocomplete on my project Symfony

I want to know how can i extract full complete address in autofill, i have 2 inputs one for search and one hidden for get full/complete address

```
<mapbox-address-autofill>
                                        {{ form_widget( form.address, {
                                            'attr': {
                                                'class': 'form-control form-control-solid font-weight-bold',
                                                'placeholder': 'Adresse de départ',
                                                'required': 'required',
                                                'autocomplete': 'address-line1'
                                            }
                                        } ) }}
                                        {{ form_widget( form.address_value, {
                                            'attr': {
                                                'autocomplete': 'full-address'
                                            }
                                        }) }}
                                    </mapbox-address-autofill>
```

I have this but with tag 'full-addresse' 'complete' 'place_name'

No one workn if you have any solution for get full address to persist this in php Symfony project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"full_address" is a property of the [feature object](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/core/autofill/#autofillsuggestion#full_address) that is returned from a [retrieve event](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/autofill/#mapboxaddressautofill.event:retrieve), but does not automatically map to any HTML form field autocomplete value. The only object properties that get mapped to HTML elements are the ones corresponding to [WHATWG standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-street-address), i.e.:

```
'street-address'
'address-line1'
'address-line2'
'address-line3'
'address-level1'
'address-level2'
'address-level3'
'address-level4'
'country'
'country-name'
'postal-code'
```

I'm not familiar with PHP, but a way to do this in Javascript would be something like:

```
const autofill = document.querySelector('mapbox-address-autofill');
const targetInput = document.getElementById('myTargetInput');
autofill.addEventListener('retrieve', (event) => {
  const featureCollection = event.detail;
  const feature = featureCollection[0];
  const fullAddress = feature.properties.full_address;
  targetInput.value = fullAddress;
});
```